# Problem with launching my app on Android Emulator (both Visual Studio and Android Studio)

Tags: android, emulation, launch

I first tried to run the Xamarin.Forms project in Visual Studio (but the same problem is in Android Studio).
I create "Hello World" on Xamarin.Forms and when I run it, it starts the emulator and then there is only Android System on the emulator, but no my program.
Then I tried to start emulator first, it doesn't work at all.
Then I tried in Android Studio. I created a project and I want to run it in Android Studio and the same happen...
I tried on diffrent computer but it didn't work in the same way...

I have recorded all my steps. You can watch it here:
https://youtu.be/izjNIP56wvI

Answer (score 0):

OK. Solved.

I just installed new emulator. Google Pixel 5.
Then from Visual Studio Device Manager I have installed x86_x64.

And when I started emulator from Device Manager it began to work.

I have tried 5 hours to start this emulator and now it is ok.